# SPServiceContext class not available in SharePoint

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, visual-web-part

I have made a web part in Visual Studio in which I am using the following class:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext
```

It is working fine. Then I created a new visual web part project and tried to use this but it says:

> The type or namespace name 'SPServiceContext' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Even though I have already added Microsoft.SharePoint at the top plus I have added its reference in project.

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you using Sandboxed solution? This class is available only in farm solutions.

Comment: Yes I am using sandboxed solution. Looks like you are right because the other project in which it is working is not sanboxed solution.

Comment: You can check availability of class in sandboxed solution on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spservicecontext%28v=office.14%29.aspx). There is a 'Available in Sandboxed Solutions' parameter (but only in SP 2010 page version).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Maybe we can help you with an alternate method...

Comment: I have a an external list with column "employee id". I am making a web part which will pass current logged in user's employee id (which is coming from UPS/AD) and then display records to him.